# Create a list out of a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a tuple of tuples like this: `t = ((4, 3), (2, 9), (7, 2), ...)`, where the first element in each nested tuple (i.e. `t[i][0]`) can range from 1 to 11 without repetition, but not necessarily every integer between 1 and 11 will be present.

I want to create a list (or tuple) `r` based on `t`, in the following way:

The resulting list `r` has a length of 11 exactly. For each index `j` in `r`, if `j + 1 === t[i][0]` for any `i`, then `r[j] = t[i][1]`, otherwise `r[j] = 0`.

This can be done by initializing `r` to `[0] * 11` first, and then loop through `t` to assign `t[i][1]` to `r[t[i][0] - 1]`:

```
t = ((4, 3), (2, 9), (7, 2), (10, 1))
r = [0] * 11
for item in t:
    r[item[0] - 1] = item[1]

r = [0, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

But is there any more efficient way (a functional way, maybe)?

Comment: "This can be done by initializing r to [0] * 11 first, and then loop through t to assign t[i][1] to r[t[i][0]]." Do you have code for this? Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Can you give the expected `r` for your example `t`?

Comment: @Haidro, added the code above.

Comment: @arshajii, i've added an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> t
((4, 3), (2, 9), (7, 2), (10, 1))
>>> d = dict(t)
>>> [d.get(el, 0) for el in xrange(1, 12)]
[0, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dictionary from `t` and populate `r` using lookups

```
t = ((4, 3), (2, 9), (7, 2))
d_t = dict(t)
r = [0]*11
r = [d_t[i+1] if i + 1 in d_t else r[i] for i, x in enumerate(r)]
print r
[0, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a mapping (by dictionary)

```
d = { v[0]:v[1] for i,v in enumerate(t) }
result = [ d[j+1] if j+1 in d else 0  for j in t ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict` and a list comprehension with conditional expression:

```
>>> dic = dict(t)
>>> [dic[i] if i in dic else 0 for i in range(1, 12)]
[0, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```